# Is there a way to initialize a pointer to an array in C (on the same line)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following line (in C):

```
char *tmp;
```

Now, I want that variable `tmp` be initialized to some pointer in my code (a few lines bellow), and after that want be initialized to an array.

Is there a way to allocate to `tmp` the pointer to a new created array on the stack, without creating another variable? So, instead of:

```
char arr[10];
tmp = arr;
```

I want to have something like this:

```
tmp = char[10];
```

Is possible something like that in C? If yes, can you give me an example?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. You cannot have `tmp` be both a pointer and later an array.

Comment: You are not talking about "pointer to an array" here. You are talking about a pointer to a char

Comment: @newacct instead of char you can put any other type. It was just an example for a better understanding.

Comment: @artaxerxe: my point is that "pointer to an array" means something completely different than what you are talking about

Comment: @newacct I edited my question. I think now it is well formed. At least I hope:). Thanks for indication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the *compound literal* feature:

```
tmp = (char[]){'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Comment: +1 for showing a feature I never heard of nor seen before and answering the question.

Comment: this will initialize tmp to a char[3] is it not?

Comment: This is called compound literal and perfectly portable to all compilers that implement modern C, that is C since 1999.

Comment: Yeah, compound literals are standard. You can also create structs in the same way. Unlike string literals, in a function they're created on the stack with the usual storage rules.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise this was now standard behaviour. Edited.

Comment: In addition, if you don't want/need to initialise each element you can create a cleared array of 10 elements with `tmp = (char[10]){}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp = alloca(10);
```

`alloca(size)` will enlarge the current stack frame to accommodate `size` more bytes and return a pointer to the newly allocated stack space.

I don't think it's a standard C function. Although it it commonly provided, its use seems to be generally frowned upon.

Comment: don't use `alloca` it is not portable and very error prone. use compound literals as in Graham's answer for fixed sized arrays, or VLA if you really need a dynamic allocation on the stack.